# Blender 2.8 - why can't I see my objects in 3D viewport?

Tags: objects, outliner, visibility

I've been working on a project for a while - saved it, reloaded later and suddenly-- large components are invisible in the 3D viewport (but visible in the Outliner).

- The objects are marked as visible, linked etc. in the Outliner.
- I've tested to see if it's local view (/) - it's not.
- All the collections in my project are visible and linked.
- I can neither focus on the objects in question, nor can I switch them to edit mode.

[image]

You can grab the project [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qero6pde3yu5hg3/narrativeDraftModel01022RS.blend?dl=0), if you want to look around.

If anybody can give me a hand here, it would be really appreciated. I'd prefer not to redo this work...!

Thanks in advance --Rev

Answer (score 1):

May be it is because of clipping. Set your clip start to something small like 0.0001m

Press 'N' in your keyboard while hovering your mouse in 3D viewport. Then under 'View' adjust clip start.